# how many actor does akka stream create in a simple flow?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

i have a stream code

```
   val source = Source.actorRef[Msg[T]](1000, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)
   val flow=source.map(println(_)).to(Sink.onComplete{case _=>println("complete")}).run()
```

after i run the code, i found from the logfile,the akka had create two actors:

```
 akka://xxxx/flow-0-0-unknown-operation#-969158424]
 akka://xxxx/flow-0-1-actorRefSource#-1265269541]
```

what is this "unknown-operation" actor?

can i rename it? i am a little confuse,becuase once i change the code as:

```
val flow=source.map(println(_)).to(Sink.onComplete{case _=>receiver.stop()})
         .named("iwantName").run()
```

and the log output as:

```
 akka://xxx/flow-0-0-unknown-operation#1904555295]   
 akka://xxx/flow-0-1-iwantName-actorRefSource#-1328507659]
```

i try to rename it to "iwantName" but it changed to another actor.

can someone explain to me pls, what is the exactly function of the 2 actor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When materializing an akka-stream graph it will at least create one actor, which is the actor actually executing the stream stages. If the graph contains asynchronous boundaries each side of the boundary will belong to a separate actor when the stream is running.

In your case the `Source.actorRef` will create one actor, and the rest of the stream will run in a separate actor. These actors are however implementation details and not something your application will interact with directly.

The actor names are weird because you will be able to materialize your graph as many times as you like, and each materialization will create actors.